# Copying data from JList to (another) JList

Tags: java, swing, collections, jlist, deprecated

Briefly, the program displays the user's chosen options(months) to a screen.

I saw the question titled with "How to copy data from one `JList` to another `JList`?" However, it was posted 5 years ago, and my question is little bit different with that article.

The problem is that the `getSelectedValues()` method is deprecated now which is used in the private inner class `ButtonListener`.

I know that the method is replaced with `getSelectedValuesList()`, but it returns a `List<E>` now and the `setListData` method accepts array as its argument, so they don't work together.

I have two questions.

1. What is `E`?
2. How can I copy multiple data from a `JList` to another `JList` (What is the most efficient way to do it? is it using `DefaultListModel`?)?

Here is the code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class MultipleIntervalSelection extends JFrame
{
   private JPanel monthPanel;
   private JPanel selectedMonthPanel;
   private JPanel buttonPanel;

   private JList<String> monthList;
   private JList<String> selectedMonthList;

   private JScrollPane scrollPane1;
   private JScrollPane scrollPane2;

   private JButton button;

   private String[] months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
                              "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", 
                              "November", "December"};

   public MultipleIntervalSelection()
   {
      setTitle("Multi Selections");

      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      buildMonthPanel();
      buildSelectedMonthsPanel();
      buildButtonPanel();

      add(monthPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      add(selectedMonthPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);            

      pack();
      setVisible(true);
   }

   private void buildMonthPanel()
   {
      monthPanel = new JPanel();

      monthList = new JList<>(months);

      monthList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

      monthList.setVisibleRowCount(6);

      scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(monthList);

      monthPanel.add(scrollPane1);
   }                            

   private void buildSelectedMonthsPanel()
   {
      selectedMonthPanel = new JPanel();

      selectedMonthList = new JList<>();

      selectedMonthList.setVisibleRowCount(6);

      scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(selectedMonthList);

      selectedMonthPanel.add(scrollPane2);
   }        

   private void buildButtonPanel()
   {
      buttonPanel = new JPanel();

      button = new JButton("Get Selections");

      button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

      buttonPanel.add(button);
   }

   private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
   {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         Object[] selections = monthList.getSelectedValues();

         selectedMonthList.setListData(selections);
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      new MultipleIntervalSelection();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the deprecated `getSelectedValues()` was changed to `getSelectedValuesList()`, therefore you must save the selected values to a `List`

Answer (score 0):

Simply get the list and transform it to an array, like this:

```
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        List<String> list = monthList.getSelectedValuesList();
        int size = list.size();
        String[] values = new String[size];
        for (int ii=0; ii<size; ii++) {
            values[ii] = list.get(ii);
        }
        selectedMonthList.setListData(values);
    }
}
```